# ¿Como transformar un dict en un byte?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentado probar el código dado por Sachin Joglekar en [un proyecto sobre redes neuronales convolucionales para clasificar los comentarios tóxicos](https://medium.com/@srjoglekar246/first-time-with-kaggle-a-convnet-to-classify-toxic-comments-with-keras-ef84b6d18328) utilizando python3. Pero tengo numeros problemas al configurar mi computadora para ello.. Por lo momento cuando utiliso `tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)` se requiere un objeto similar a un byte, y parece que le doy un 'dict'. ¿Entonces como transformar  un dict en un byte ? ¿O como adaptar mi codigo ?

Aqui esta algunos de los datos :

```
{'comment_text': "Yo bitch Ja Rule is more succesful then you'll ever be whats up with you and hating you sad mofuckas...i should bitch slap ur pethedic white faces and get you to kiss my ass you guys sicken me. Ja rule is about pride in da music man. dont diss that shit on him. and nothin is wrong bein like tupac he was a brother too...fuckin white boys get things right next time.,", 'id': '00001cee341fdb12'}
{'comment_text': '== From RfC == \n\n The title is fine as it is, IMO.', 'id': '0000247867823ef7'}
{'comment_text': '" \n\n == Sources == \n\n * Zawe Ashton on Lapland —  /  "', 'id': '00013b17ad220c46'}
{'comment_text': ":If you have a look back at the source, the information I updated was the correct form. I can only guess the source hadn't updated. I shall update the information once again but thank you for your message.", 'id': '00017563c3f7919a'}
{'comment_text': "I don't anonymously edit articles at all.", 'id': '00017695ad8997eb'}
{'comment_text': 'Thank you for understanding. I think very highly of you and would not revert without discussion.', 'id': '0001ea8717f6de06'}
{'comment_text': 'Please do not add nonsense to Wikipedia. Such edits are considered vandalism and quickly undone. If you would like to experiment, please use the sandbox instead. Thank you.   -', 'id': '00024115d4cbde0f'}
{'comment_text': ':Dear god this site is horrible.', 'id': '000247e83dcc1211'}
{'comment_text': '" \n Only a fool can believe in such numbers. \n The correct number lies between 10 000 to 15 000. \n Ponder the numbers carefully.  \n\n This error will persist for a long time as it continues to reproduce... The latest reproduction I know is from ENCYCLOPÆDIA BRITANNICA ALMANAC 2008 wich states \n Magnittude: 8.7 (fair enough) \n victims: 70 000 (today 10 000 to 15 000 is not ""a lot"" so I guess people just come out with a number that impresses enough, I don\'t know. But I know this: it\'s just a shameless lucky number that they throw in the air. \n GC \n\n "', 'id': '00025358d4737918'}
{'comment_text': "== Double Redirects == \n\n When fixing double redirects, don't just blank the outer one, you need edit it to point it to the final target, unless you think it's inappropriate, in which case, it needs to be nominated at WP:RfD", 'id': '00026d1092fe71cc'}
```

Aqui esta el error :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Kaggle$ python3 medium.py 
Using TensorFlow backend.
Total number of texts: 159571
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "medium.py", line 107, in <module>
    tokenizer, word_index, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val = get_datasets(texts, targets)
  File "medium.py", line 37, in get_datasets
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/preprocessing/text.py", line 194, in fit_on_texts
    self.split)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/preprocessing/text.py", line 46, in text_to_word_sequence
    text = text.translate(translate_map)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'
```

Aqui esta el entero codigo :

```
from backports import csv
import numpy as np
import sys
import io


# Helps in reading long texts
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)


def get_texts_and_targets(filename):
    texts = []
    targets = []

    with io.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for i, row in enumerate(readCSV):
            if i == 0:
                # Header row
                continue
            texts.append(row[1].strip().encode('ascii', 'replace'))
            targets.append(np.array([float(x) for x in row[2:]]))
    print("Total number of texts: %s" % len(texts))
    return texts, targets

from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

# Max number of input words in any sample
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 200
VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.1

def get_datasets(texts, targets, tokenizer=None):
    if tokenizer is None:
        tokenizer = Tokenizer()
        tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)

    sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)
    word_index = tokenizer.word_index
    data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)

    targets = np.asarray(targets)

    indices = np.arange(data.shape[0])
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
    data = data[indices]
    targets = targets[indices]
    nb_validation_samples = int(VALIDATION_SPLIT * data.shape[0])

    x_train = data[:-nb_validation_samples]
    y_train = targets[:-nb_validation_samples]
    x_val = data[-nb_validation_samples:]
    y_val = targets[-nb_validation_samples:]

    return tokenizer, word_index, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val

# For word embeddings, he used the Glove Twitter vectors with 100 dimensions. 

from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

def load_glove_model():
    word2vec = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
            os.path.join(WORD2VEC_FOLDER,
                'word2vec_twitter_glove.txt'),
            binary=False)
    return word2vec

# embedding layer in Keras
def get_embedding_layer(word_index, gensim_model):
    embedding_dim = len(gensim_model.wv['apple'])
    embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index) + 1, embedding_dim))
    for word, i in word_index.items():
        if word in gensim_model.wv.vocab:
            embedding_matrix[i] = gensim_model.wv[word]
    embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
            embedding_dim,
            weights=[embedding_matrix],
            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
            trainable=True)
    return embedding_layer

#We use 2 Convolutional+Max-Pooling blocks followed by 3 dense layers:
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model

N_TARGET_CLASSES = 6

def get_convnet_model(embedding_layer):
    sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
    embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
    x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
    x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
    x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    #Sigmoid (and not Softmax) is the more appropriate objective function here, since each sample could belong to multiple classes (A comment could be an insult and obscene at the same time).
    preds = Dense(N_TARGET_CLASSES, activation='sigmoid')(x)

    model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
    return model

# Training with  Adagrad (with its default settings) as it worked best for this use-case. 
texts, targets = get_texts_and_targets('data/train.csv')
tokenizer, word_index, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val = get_datasets(texts, targets)
word2vec = load_word2vec_model()
embedding_layer = get_embedding_layer(word_index, word2vec)
model = get_convnet_model(embedding_layer)
# The binary_crossentropy objective is Keras version of log-loss
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
        optimizer='adagrad',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=2, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
```

Comment: ¿Algún motivo para usar `backports.csv`?

Comment: @ChemaCortes no si no para probar Sachin Joglekar código. Además, acabo de agregar su enlace

Comment: Si usas python3, no necesitas de *backports*. Prueba con `import csv` en su lugar, porque creo que puede tener algo qué ver.